# How to know a filter device driver is hooked to a com port

Tags: windows, serial-port, driver, wdk, ioctl

I have been trying to determine if a USB serial port (COM) port is monitored by a system bus driver without success. Basically I have an application that monitors a com port via a filter device driver. I was able to do this after reading this article from the Dr Dobb's magazine. Now what am trying to achieve in a seperate app is to be able to determine if there is an app hooked to a particular com port using a filter device driver. Can anyone help or guide me

Comment: This is off topic on SO, as it is a question more suited to the Super User forum for general computer issues.